# Android Bluetooth `InputStream` doesn't receive data

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi which I am using to read some sensor data and then trying to send that data through Bluetooth RFCOMM socket to Android phone. I can send data from the Android phone to the Raspberry Pi without problems but for some reason I am not able to read the sensor data with the Android phone sent by the Raspberry Pi.

The `write` function on the Raspberry Pi always returns the right amount of bytes that have been sent and on the Android side I have a thread reading the `InputStream` and there is a `available` function to check if there is any bytes to read but it almost every time returns nothing. However, it sometimes reads (maybe 1 time of 20) the sensor data and after the message handler has passed the data back to the another activity and printed the data on a text view, the program crashes.

Maybe someone could give me some explanation why the `InputStream` isn't receiving any data even though the Raspberry Pi sends the data. Huge thanks in advance!

Here is my BluetoothTransferThread class:

```
public class BluetoothTransferThread extends Thread {

private final BluetoothSocket connectedSocket;
private final InputStream mmInStream;
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
private Context context;
private final Handler threadHandler;

public BluetoothTransferThread(BluetoothSocket socket, Context context, Handler mHandler) {
    this.context = context;
    connectedSocket = socket;
    threadHandler = mHandler;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;

    // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
    try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    mmInStream = tmpIn;
    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
}

public void run() {

    //Send a transfer thread created message to activity
    threadHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothClientActivity.TRANSFER_THREAD_CREATED).sendToTarget();

    int[] buffer;
    int readByte;
    int i = 0, bytesAvailable;

    /**
     * Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
     */
    while (true) {

        try {

            //Check if there is bytes available to read in the InputStream
            bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();
            if(bytesAvailable > 0) {
                buffer = new int[bytesAvailable];
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), String.format("value = %d", bytesAvailable));

                /*
                 * Read the stream byte at a time and store it to a buffer until we have received the end of the frame char
                 */
                do {
                    //readByte = dInputStream.readUnsignedByte();
                    readByte = mmInStream.read();
                    buffer[i] = readByte;
                    i++;
                } while (readByte != 0xEE);

                //Send the received data through handler back to activity
                threadHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothClientActivity.MESSAGE_READ, buffer).sendToTarget();
            }
            try {
                currentThread().sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Write to the connected OutStream.
 */
public void write(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        mmOutStream.write(buffer);
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Wrote to the socket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Couldn't write to the socket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Close the transfer thread
 */
public void cancel() {
    try {
        connectedSocket.close();
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Transfer thread socket closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Couldn't close the transfer thread socket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And here is the Raspberry Pi's side code snippet:

```
case READ_SENSOR_DATA:

            /* Serialize the data and send it through the socket */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&sensorData->mutex1);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&sensorData->mutex5);
            serializationLengthPtr = serializeStruct(sendBuffer, sensorData);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&sensorData->mutex1);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&sensorData->mutex5);
            sendBuffer[8] = FRAME_END_CHAR;

            bytes_sent = write(client, sendBuffer, serializationLengthPtr - sendBuffer + 1);
            if(bytes_sent <= 0) {
                perror("Write failed!\n");
                socketCloseFlag = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", bytes_sent);
            }
            break;
```